Monitor IMAP traffic
I would like to monitor IMAP traffic that comes between my Outlook and IMAP server. I can monitor traffic with Wireshark listening on port 993. But how to decrypt traffic?

Which cipher suite is used? According to Can't decrypt imaps traffic in Wireshark depending upon which cipher suite it may not be possible to decrypt the traffic.

To decrypt IMAP traffic captured with Wireshark, you can follow these steps:

Set Up SSLKEYLOGFILE Environment Variable: This variable will store the keys used for encryption. You need to set this environment variable before starting your email client (Outlook in this case). Here’s how you can do it:


On Windows, open Command Prompt and run:
set SSLKEYLOGFILE=C:\path\to\sslkeys.log


On macOS or Linux, open Terminal and run:
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/path/to/sslkeys.log




Start Your Email Client: After setting the environment variable, start Outlook. The keys used for encryption will be logged to the file specified in the SSLKEYLOGFILE variable.
Capture Traffic with Wireshark: Start capturing traffic on port 993 using Wireshark. Make sure to save the capture file.
Load the Key Log File in Wireshark: In Wireshark, go to Edit > Preferences > Protocols > TLS. In the (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename field, enter the path to the SSLKEYLOGFILE you set earlier.
Decrypt the Traffic: Wireshark will use the keys from the log file to decrypt the captured traffic. You should now be able to see the decrypted IMAP traffic.

In addition, you may refer to the link for more ideas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/727905/alert-or-monitoring-for-traffic-manager-service-go
Hope it helps.
